# ActiveReport_ReportStart bind subreport script

Tags: c#-4.0, activereports

I'm using Active Reports Subreport tool,
I want to bind data source in ActiveReport_ReportStart as script by connecting Oracle.
I'm using the script below but I'm having this error:
**Error Message:[DBNETLIB][Connection Open (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. Invalid connection string attribute.**

```
public void ActiveReport_ReportStart()
{
string connString = "Provider=SQLOleDB;User Id=XXX;Password=XX;Server=XXX;Service      Name=XX;Direct=True;Persist Security Info=True";
string sqlString = @"sql query";
DataDynamics.ActiveReports.DataSources.OleDBDataSource ds = new     DataDynamics.ActiveReports.DataSources.OleDBDataSource();
ds.ConnectionString = connString;
ds.SQL = sqlString;
rpt.DataSource = ds;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as ActiveReports goes, I don't see anything wrong. I haven't had time to look into this in any detail, but it is probably your connection string. The error message is from SQLServer/OLEDB, it is just bubbling up via ActiveReports.

Try using the same connection string with a System.Data.OleDB.OleDBConnection object and see if it works. If you get an error there too, it is definitely your connection string. 
If not, let me know and I'll have a closer look.

You might also want to try to use the built-in connection string builder in the ActieReports Designer and get it working there and then copy it into the script.

Comment: BTW: You might want to try the SqlDBDataSource rather than OleDBDatasource since it looks like you're trying to use SQL Server directly.

Comment: thanks for reply, it is actually oracle connection, so ı changed the connection string to : Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection con = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = "POOLING=FALSE;User Id=XX;Password=XX;Server=XX;Direct=True;Sid=XX;Persist Security Info=True";
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataAdapter da = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataAdapter(sqlString, con);
   da.Fill(dt);
   sbrpt.DataSource = dt; But this time I'm having "Type or namespace Devart could not be found!"

Comment: How can I add reference to the script?

Comment: I have tried ; arDesigner.Report.AddScriptReference("Devart.Data.Oracle.dll"); but it does not work!

Comment: @kubilaybayraktar the error is clearly due to an invalid connection string. The one defined in your original question is definitely not a valid Oracle connection string. Try testing one with the OLEDB Provider in .NET itself (or using visual studio's Add Connection tool in the Server Explorer). Also there are some examples of Oracle for OLEDB Connection strings at http://connectionstrings.com/oracle#p15  Also, when using OLEDB it will still require that you have a valid oracle client installed. I'm not sure about the versions and such, you'll have to check with oracle on that.